# How to loop multiple array values

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have arrays:

```
array1 = ['abc1.1', 'def2.2', 'fgh3.3']
array2 = ['/a/b/c', '/d/e/f', '/f/g/h']
```

I'm expecting to print as below:

```
abc1.1
/a/b/c
def2.2
/d/e/f
fgh3.3
/f/g/h
```

I'm not sure how to get the expected output. Please suggest.

My attempt is as below:

```
array1.each do |x|
  puts "#{x}"
  array2.each do |y|
    puts "#{y}"
  end
end
```

And it results as below:

```
abc1.1
/a/b/c
/d/e/f
/f/g/h
cde2.2
/a/b/c
/d/e/f
/f/g/h
fgh3.3
/a/b/c
/d/e/f
/f/g/h
```

During every iteration of `array1`, it completely iterates the `array2`, then goes back to `array1`.

Answer (score 4):

```
array1.zip(array2).each do |x, y|
  puts x, y
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
array1.each_with_index do |a1, index|
 puts a1
 puts array2[index]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First iterate over `array1` then over `array2`

```
array1.each_with_index do |x, index|
  puts x
  puts array2[index]
end
```

Will produce

```
abc1.1
/a/b/c
def2.2
/d/e/f
fgh3.3
/f/g/h
```